# How can i override the event variable in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, document

On click of document anywhere by default, it is coming as false
I want to change it to true how can I do that..?

```
jQuery(document).click(function(e) {
console.log(e); //e.target.isConnected = false;
e.target.isConnected = true; //i want to overwrite
--logic--
--logic--
});
```

I am getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'isConnected'
>   of object '[object HTMLAnchorElement]'

My application is in angular 4

Comment: Error is quite verbose _read only property_

Comment: What's the use case for this? Why do you need to pretend something is false when it isn't?

Comment: There is a `popup` which is useful in two pages , when I come from `child link` to `parent` by keeping child popup on that popup should be not visible now it is visible in parent.! but now it is visible @ADyson

Comment: what does any of that have to do with clicking on `document`?

Comment: on click of document outside of the `div pop` I am hiding the `pop`

Comment: Ok, but what does faking its connected status have to do with that? If you want to hide it, then hide it. This seems unrelated.

Comment: when I click outside of that `div pop` it should hide. because of that, i used it by seeing in the event dom.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/isConnected#Examples You can make it to true with this.

Comment: No I don't follow you. What relationship does the isConnected status have to hiding your popup. You can just write code to hide it. If it's already hidden, nothing will happen, no problem. And hiding it doesn't disconnect it from the DOM anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `isConnected` is property holding a status information and because of that it is read only, and cannot be changed using an assignment.

[Node.isConnected](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/isConnected)

> The `isConnected` read-only property of the Node interface returns a boolean indicating whether or not the Node is connected (directly or indirectly) to the context object, e.g. the Document object in the case of the normal DOM, or the ShadowRoot in the case of a shadow DOM.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know is there any alternate solution to my question ..?

Comment: @Mrworldwide in your question you ask how to change `isConnected`. But you do not say what you want to achieve with that. If you explain what your desired result is then it might be possible to tell you how to solve that.